# Array like input for Sklearn LogisticRegressionCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Originally, I read the data from a `.csv` file, but here I build the dataframe from lists so the problem can be reproduced. The aim is to train a logistic regression model with cross-validation using `LogisticRegressionCV`.

```
indeps = ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F']
dep = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

data = [indeps, dep] 
cols = ['state', 'cat_bins']

data_dict = dict((x[0], x[1]) for x in zip(cols, data))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
df.tail()

    cat_bins    state
45  0.0           F
46  0.0           M
47  0.0           M
48  0.0           F
49  0.0           F


'''Use Pandas' to encode independent variables.  Notice that
 we are returning a sparse dataframe '''

def heat_it2(dataframe, lst_of_columns):
    dataframe_hot = pd.get_dummies(dataframe,
                                   prefix = lst_of_columns,
                                   columns = lst_of_columns, sparse=True,)
    return dataframe_hot

train_set_hot = heat_it2(df, ['state'])
train_set_hot.head(2)

    cat_bins    state_F     state_M
0     1.0         0            1
1     1.0         1            0

'''Use the dataframe to set up the prospective inputs to the model as numpy arrays'''

indeps_hot = ['state_F', 'state_M']

X = train_set_hot[indeps_hot].values
y = train_set_hot['cat_bins'].values

print 'X-type:', X.shape, type(X)
print 'y-type:', y.shape, type(y)
print 'X has shape, is an array and has length:\n', hasattr(X, 'shape'), hasattr(X, '__array__'), hasattr(X, '__len__')
print 'yhas shape, is an array and has length:\n', hasattr(y, 'shape'), hasattr(y, '__array__'), hasattr(y, '__len__')
print 'X does have attribute fit:\n',hasattr(X, 'fit')
print 'y does have attribute fit:\n',hasattr(y, 'fit')

X-type: (50, 2) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
y-type: (50,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
X has shape, is an array and has length:
True True True
yhas shape, is an array and has length:
True True True
X does have attribute fit:
False
y does have attribute fit:
False
```

So, the inputs to the regressor seem to have the necessary properties for the `.fit` method.  They are **numpy arrays wit the right shape**. `X` is an array with the dimensions `[n_samples, n_features]`, and `y` is a vector with shape `[n_samples,]` Here is the documentation:

> > fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]
> >
> > ```
> > Fit the model according to the given training data.
> > Parameters: 
> >
> > X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
> >
> >     Training vector, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
> >   y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
> >
> > Target vector relative to X.
> > ```

....

Now we try to fit the regressor:

```
logmodel = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs =1, dual=False , scoring = accuracy_score, penalty = 'l2')
logmodel.fit(X, y)

...

    TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got estimator LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
    intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
    penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
    verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

The source of the error message seems to be in scikits' validation.py module, [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py).

The only section of the code that raises this error message is the following function-snippet:

```
def _num_samples(x):
    """Return number of samples in array-like x."""
    if hasattr(x, 'fit'):
        # Don't get num_samples from an ensembles length!
        raise TypeError('Expected sequence or array-like, got '
                        'estimator %s' % x)
    etc.
```

**Question:** Since the parameters with which we are fitting the model(`X` and `y`) do not have the attribute 'fit', why is this error message raised

Using python 2.7 on Canopy 1.7.4.3348 (64 bit) with scikit-learn 18.01-3 and pandas 0.19.2-2

Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the `scoring` argument. You have passed `accuracy_score`. The signature of `accuracy_score` is `accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred[, ...])`. But in the module [logistic.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py)

```
if isinstance(scoring, six.string_types):
    scoring = SCORERS[scoring]
for w in coefs:
    // Other code
    if scoring is None:
        scores.append(log_reg.score(X_test, y_test))
    else:
        scores.append(scoring(log_reg, X_test, y_test))
```

Since you have passed `accuracy_score`, it doesnt fit the first line above. 
And `scores.append(scoring(log_reg, X_test, y_test))` is used to score the estimator. But as I said above, here the arguments doesnt match the required arguments of `accuracy_score`. Hence the error.

**Workaround**:Use [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer)(accuracy_score) in LogisticRegressionCV for scoring or simply pass the string 'accuracy'

```
logmodel = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs =1, dual=False , 
                                scoring = make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
                                penalty = 'l2')

                         OR

logmodel = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs =1, dual=False , 
                                scoring = 'accuracy', 
                                penalty = 'l2')
```

**Note**:

This maybe a bug on part of the `logistic.py` module or in the documentation of LogisticRegressionCV they should have clarified the signature of scoring function.

You may submit [an issue to the github and see how it goes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8333)  **Done**

Comment: Thank you, both your suggestions avoid the error.  Can you please also tell me which section of the source code the error message comes from.

Comment: The source of the error is same as you have pin pointed in the question. But why it came, because the scoring function was supplied incorrect argument. From where the incorrect argument was supplied, that I have shown in my answer in the first code snippet.